# New VS for Mac install exception on trying to open storyboard

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I installed Visual Studio for Mac - Community and followed the Xamarin.iOS tutorial from the Xamarin site. When I select Main.storyboard I get an exception - Am I doing something wrong?:

**My installation info:**
=== Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac ===

Version 7.2.2 (build 7)
Installation UUID: adfed099-1ec0-45d3-b154-d4ce3ffe4bd3
Runtime:
    Mono 5.4.1.6 (2017-06/1f4613aa1ac) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

```
Package version: 504010006
```

=== NuGet ===

Version: 4.3.1.4445

=== .NET Core ===

Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Version: 2.0.0
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/Sdks
SDK Version: 2.0.0
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.5.6
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 8.0.2.1 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk
    Supported Android versions:
        6.0 (API level 23)
        7.1 (API level 25)

SDK Tools Version: 25.2.5
SDK Platform Tools Version: 25.0.5
SDK Build Tools Version: 25.0.3

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.3.2
Hash: 461f09a
Branch: 1.3-release
Build date: Tue, 03 Oct 2017 18:26:57 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 9.1 (13532)
Build 9B55

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 11.2.1.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 12e80e01
Branch: d15-4-xi
Build date: 2017-10-13 12:03:42-0400

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 3.8.1.0 (Visual Studio Community)

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 702020007
Git revision: 2236098c68f51eeb447cb947a87371d1e84f6213
Build date: 2017-10-23 11:43:05-04
Xamarin addins: eaa605cf97f25ce184949f32c712b465ca96f665
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-d15-4

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.12.6
Darwin 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0
    Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017
    root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

**The Exception:**
System.NotSupportedException: Could not parse xml ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.GetCurrentXcodeVersion () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:851 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.get_XcodeVersion () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:160 
  at MonoTouch.Design.IModelObjectContextExtensions.WithIdProvider (MonoTouch.Design.IModelObjectContext context, MonoTouch.Design.IIdProvider idProvider) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/IModelObjectContextExtensions.cs:10 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElementsAndAttributes (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x0003d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:278 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result, Xamarin.Designer.ProxiedException error) [0x000d0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:370 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:245 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElement (MonoTouch.Design.LayoutGuides layoutGuides, MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:1019 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:313 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElements (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x000da] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:324 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElementsAndAttributes (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:274 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result, Xamarin.Designer.ProxiedException error) [0x000d0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:370 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:245 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElement (MonoTouch.Design.ProxiedViewController model, MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x000f3] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:751 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:313 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElements (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x000da] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:324 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElementsAndAttributes (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:274 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result, Xamarin.Designer.ProxiedException error) [0x000d0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:370 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:245 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElement (MonoTouch.Design.Scene scene, MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x0008b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:689 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:313 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElements (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x000da] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:324 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElementsAndAttributes (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result) [0x0002d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:274 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Object result, Xamarin.Designer.ProxiedException error) [0x000d0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:370 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:245 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.ParseElement (MonoTouch.Design.Storyboard sb, MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00040] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:884 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.Parse (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context, System.Boolean skipImageGeneration) [0x00021] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:225 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.Parse (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:214 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.Parse (System.Xml.Linq.XElement xml, MonoTouch.Design.DeviceFamily targetRuntime, MonoTouch.Design.IModelObjectContext modelObjectContext) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:203 
  at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession+d__163.MoveNext () [0x00130] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/2236098c/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client/IPhoneDesignerSession.cs:412

Contents of /Users/daniel/Library/Logs/VisualStudio/7.0/iOSDesigner.2017-11-03__22-14-31.log:
MDAddinsHash: eaa605cf97f25ce184949f32c712b465ca96f665

**Any clues?**

Comment: If you right-click on the storyboard and choose Xcode Interface Builder does the storyboard open ok?

Comment: Yes, that does open it in XCode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is your version of XCode? Xibs that are saved using XCode 9.1 can not be opened from Visual studio.

- Download an older version of XCode
- Open your file with it
- Save it
- Then open it from visual studio.

Updated:

Some more steps

- Switch to beta channel (in more detail):

  Click on visual studio menu (upper left corner)

  Click on check for updates

  Swicht to beta channel

  Update

Comment: I was on XCode 9.0 when I installed VS and got the error. I then upgraded to 9.1. I am not pulling in Xibs I am creating new in VS

Comment: Try to switch to beta channel.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what that means?

Comment: Click on visual studio menu (upper left corner) and then check for updates. Switch to beta channel and download the newer beta version. Check if the problem persist

Comment: Aha, you mean I should use the beta preview version?

Comment: Yes that did the trick, update your answer so I can mark it as the solution!

Comment: I have been struggling on XCode to use auto-layout to make an app I'm trying to build scale across all form factors iphone/ipad and in desperation is now trying Xamarin and will try to build for iOS and Andriod. Is there a good tutorial on doing layout that works/scales correctly - it's not a simple layout? I know this is not the place to ask, but any direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Check for adding and removing variations in constraints and ui elements